# Excel file is not download from the directory using Java

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc

In my application, I have an option to download the excel file from the folder by the user, all functions are working well but it shows only the response in the console and I can not download the excel file at the same time the browser does not show the save or download option.

**Note :** I used all possible *ContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")*.

```
 String downloadFolder = request.getRealPath(fileDetail.getFilePath()+fileDetail.getFileName());

    Path file = Paths.get(downloadFolder);
    if(Files.exists(file)){
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Demo.xlsx");

        try {
            Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to download the excel file when the method is called.Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to open xlsx file in Notepad++?

Comment: And the problem is what exactly? Do you expect to be able to view an `.xls` in Notepad? Does not seem like you should be able to to me.

Comment: I want to download the excel file from the folder using java

Comment: How can I download the excel file from a folder using java

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing the file as belows

InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

//Copy bytes from source to destination(outputstream in this example), closes both streams.

FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());

Comment: excel file not yet downloadable

Answer (score 0):

Try this for downloading file

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");


     response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=check.xlsx"); // Used to name the download file and its format

     File my_file = new File("E://outputtext.xlsx"); // We are downloading .xlsx file, in the format of doc with name check - check.xlsx


     OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int length;
     while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
     in.close();
     out.flush();
}
```

Comment: The Excel file is not downloading

Comment: No errors are shown. When I call the above method it shows the output in the console like  áÄvÕõÕö™GJy(v½*«¸¨¡KÉß#FÓñD±Ï.W ¥†=™ZÆMYÞbø®ÕBSí­†°·7 ê“Ï›×–¦é
?ˆ9LìÒ™ but the excel is not download

Answer (score 0):

I guess since the flush() is invoked in the consective step . It is not working properly.

Try to use finally block to flush..

Comment: you are telling like this: finally {
            out.flush();
        } right?

Comment: This also doing the same file not download

Comment: You have to write your file to outputstream and not copy 

Follow this link

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/